# Can you help me identify this serif font?

Tags: font-identification

I have to rebuild a flattened file from scratch and have no information about the font and Photoshop style used. I have been able to recreate the Photoshop style, but I have a hard time identifying the used font.

[image: sample]

Can you help me identify this serif font?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to note that I've already tried the usual font-identification sites… with no success. Even asking some of the "expert" forums turned up with no result.

Comment: Do you have more of the image? There might be more defining characters. Also are these all small caps?

Comment: There apparently isn't any difference between upper- and lowercase letters. That's what makes it hard for me to narrow it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just received an email from someone I've met and asked in a typo-forum last week. She proposed to try out a font is called *"Water Street"*.

So, I grabbed myself a copy online, installed it to the system, and - after some tweaking - it indeed seems to match up!

[image: font comparing and tweaking]

Funny enough, the font's description reads: *"A wacky little serif font"*.

[image: A wacky little serif font]

I can surely agree that it has been a *whacky* experience to identify this one during the past three weeks. Also, the *width* and *letter-spacing* tweaks did not help making it easier to identify. Oh well, at least I now have the answer to my question.

To everyone who has spend his/her precious time trying to help me: thank you. I appreciate your efforts!